# Google script search and replace regex

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Im trying to run a very basic Google Script on a document.
    docBody = docBody.replaceText(searchStr, replaceStr);

It works perfectly when the searchStr = 'Name' for example, but when I try to replace '[Name]' the script hangs and produces garbage in the document. I realise that the searchStr parameter is a regular expression and I have tried :

\[Name\]

/\[Name\]/g

(\[Name\])

All with no success...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've read elsewhere that you may need to double-escape the square brackets even in single-quoted strings. I'm not sure I believe this, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing

```
searchStr = '\[Name\]';
```

then that should work, without slashes, without modifiers, without groups. If you're using double-quotes, make sure to double-escape:

```
searchStr = "\\[Name\\]";
```

Comment: Double quotes with double slashes did it, single quotes with single slashes not.. Thanks a mil!